# Tensorflow c_api (1.13.2) - Import LSTM .pb: Expected input[1] to be a control input

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, lstm, c-api

I'm currently working on importing a trained (python3.8, TF==2.3) LSTM-Model by using the C-API (TF==1.13.2). I have to stick with this software versions. I try to show my steps so far using a dummy-example.

My model description (for dummy import purpose) using the tensorflow-cli using

`python3.8 ~/path/to/tensorflow/python/tools/saved_model_cli.py show --dir ~/path/to/model/folder --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default` is:

```
    The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
      inputs['input_1'] tensor_info:
          dtype: DT_FLOAT
          shape: (-1, 2, 1)
          name: serving_default_input_1:0
    The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
      outputs['dense'] tensor_info:
          dtype: DT_FLOAT
          shape: (-1, 1)
          name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
    Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I try to import the graph-structure using:

```cpp
uint8_t m_NumInputs = 1;
TF_Output* m_Input_ = static_cast<TF_Output*>(malloc(sizeof(TF_Output) * m_NumInputs));
TF_Output t0 = {TF_GraphOperationByName(m_Graph_, "serving_default_input_1"), 0};
m_Input_[0] = t0;

//********* Get Output tensor
uint8_t m_NumOutputs = 1;
TF_Output* m_Output_ = static_cast<TF_Output*>(malloc(sizeof(TF_Output) * m_NumOutputs));
TF_Output t2 = {TF_GraphOperationByName(m_Graph_, "StatefulPartitionedCall"), 0};
```

After declaring Input-Values I run a Session with:

```cpp
TF_Tensor** InputValues = static_cast<TF_Tensor**>(malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*) * m_NumInputs));
TF_Tensor** OutputValues = static_cast<TF_Tensor**>(malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*) * m_NumOutputs));

const std::vector<std::int64_t> dims = {1, 2, 1};
const auto data_size = std::accumulate(dims.begin(), dims.end(), sizeof(float), std::multiplies<std::int64_t>{});

auto data = static_cast<float*>(std::malloc(data_size));
std::vector<float> vals = {1.0, 1.0};
std::copy(vals.begin(), vals.end(), data); // init input_vals.

auto tensor = TF_NewTensor(
        TF_FLOAT,
        dims.data(), static_cast<int>(dims.size()),
        data, data_size,
        &NoOpDeallocator, nullptr
);

InputValues[0] = tensor;

TF_SessionRun(
        m_Session_, NULL,
        m_Input_, InputValues, m_NumInputs,
        m_Output_, OutputValues, m_NumOutputs,
        NULL, 0, NULL ,
        m_Status_
);

void* buff = TF_TensorData(OutputValues[0]);
float* offsets = static_cast<float*>(buff);
```

At `TF_SessionRun()` I receive the following Error:

```
Expected input[1] == 'TensorArrayV2_1/element_shape:output:0' to be a control input.
    In {{node TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack}}
     [[{{node sequential/lstm/PartitionedCall}}]]
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall}}]]
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall}}]]
```

And I just don't know what is meant with a control input in this context. In software-block two I set `input[1]` to zero because in the cli-output this is suggested when showing the "name".

I tried several different layers and I only receive this error when I use layers for time-series (LSTM, GRU). Does anyone have a clue what I might have missed here? Thanks for every suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with python 3.6.8, Tensorflow python version 2.3.0 and Tensorflow Java version 1.13.1. After updating the Java version to 1.15.0 it was fixed and I was able to predict with the LSTM layer in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed it seems to be a version problem. I used the Tensorflow 2.3.1 shared library and was able to sucessfully import the model in c++.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles about this problem, here is what I did to confirm that the problem is related to the used Tensorflow versions:

I included the TF2.3.1 shared-library, exported an TF2.3.1 model in Python and imported the model in successful in c++.

After that I downgraded the Python model to version 1.13.1 and used the TF1.13.1 shared-library to import the model successful in c++.

Answer (score 0):

According to tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/function.cc, control input must start with '^'. You can modify node_def in all occurrences of 'TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack' by prepending '^' in input[1]